# How to get Doxygen to show properly the class hierarchy when derived types are in a separate module

Tags: fortran, doxygen

here is my problem: when I generate a Doxygen documentation for my object-oriented Fortran code, the derived classes are not linked properly to the base class. The derived classes are defined in separate modules in order to organize them into "short" files.

If I have the class `myclass` in module `mod_myclass`, and a derived class `myderclass` in module `mod_myderclass`, the hierarchy drawn by Doxygen looks as follows:

[image: Doxygen output]

instead of simply:
`mod_myclass::Myclass <----- mod_myderclass::Myderclass`.

I tried to switch the different options of the Doxyfile, such as `OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN` or `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES`, without success.

In order to illustrate this, this is the file `mod_myclass.f90`:

```
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!     FILE mod_myclass.f90
!>    @brief   Definition of base class myclass
!!    @file    mod_myclass.f90
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!     MODULE mod_myclass
!>    @brief Define base class myclass
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MODULE mod_myclass
IMPLICIT NONE

!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!     CLASS Myclass
!>    @brief   base class myclass
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TYPE :: Myclass

  END TYPE
END MODULE
```

And is the file containing the derived class `mod_myderclass.f90`:

```
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!     FILE mod_myderclass.f90
!>    @brief   Definition of derived class myderclass
!!    @file    mod_myderclass.f90
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!     MODULE mod_myderclass
!>    @brief Define derived class myclass
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MODULE mod_myderclass
  USE mod_myclass
IMPLICIT NONE

!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!     CLASS myderclass
!>    @brief derived class myderclass
!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TYPE, EXTENDS(Myclass) :: Myderclass
  END TYPE
END MODULE
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? Might be useful to show what you got by means of an image in the original question and indicating here what you expect based on that image and nut just have some textual explanation.

Comment: I am using Doxygen v1.8.11.
I added an image of the output. It actually looks like an uppercase issue: when I remove the uppercase for the initial letter of my class names in the Fortran file I end up with the right output.
Yet, if I want to keep upper-cased class names, I see that whatever the value of the field `CASE_SENSE_NAMES` in the Doxyfile, I get the wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen version 1.8.11 is a bit old  (December 2015), the current version is 1.8.15.
When running 1.8.15 on the example I get:

[image]

Is this what you expected? In that case please update your doxygen version.

Comment: This is indeed what I expect. Yet, I have edited the MWE since yesterday, since the copy/paste I used to write it took off the upper case. Are you sure that the example you run has upper-cased class names ?
I just tried with doxygen v1.8.15 and got the same wrong result as before...
Thank you for your help, I appreciate.

Comment: Fortran is case insensitive so all names are translated to lower case. In case you have a case where uppercase characters are and the picture is not correct, please let us know.

Comment: I just took the the code of the site here again and reran and looks OK (in the Doxyfile I only set `HAVE_DOT=YES`, rest is default; easy to check for doxygen 1.8.15 with `doxygen -x`).